# Continue loop after getting alert test from browser in protractor jasmine test

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, protractor

I am implementing Protrator framework with jasmine runner in my angular app. I click on each element with expected result. Now I have a list of companies in my app. each company has two or three machines is side bar. I implemented two for loops that with loop throug the company and machines as well. Now in one machine list there is an error and as a result is shows alert from localhost. For this reason the loop breaks and fails. I want to implement a condition there so that it can detect the condition and continue from the loop. But I could not get it how can I implement that.

My test code

```
    for (let company = 0; company < await companyOption.count(); company++) {
                await companyOption.get(company);

                for (let machine = 0; machine < await machineList.count(); machine++) {
                        await click.onto(machineList.get(machine));

                  if (window.alert()) {
                   //here i want to implement if browser.switchto.alert() is appear then test should be continue to next loop
                        } else {
                            await expect(machineList.get(machine).isSelected());

                   }

             .................... other code
      }
```

Alert code in typescript

```
    ngOnInit() {

    this.route.paramMap.switchMap((params: ParamMap, index) => this.machineService.load(parseInt(params.get("machineId")))).subscribe(machine => {
        this.machine = machine;
        if (this.machine.type === null)
            window.alert("No machine type assigned for " + this.machine.name + "\nAssign a type to view the details.");


    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (let company = 0; company < await companyOption.count(); company++) {

    await companyOption.get(company);

    for (let machine = 0; machine < await machineList.count(); machine++) {

        await click.onto(machineList.get(machine));
        // solution! //
        let errorMessage; // define a variable, which is currently undefined

        try {
            // try run this code, if alert is not present it'll throw an error
            // if alert is present it skips is
            await browser.switchTo().alert().accept(); 
        } catch (e) {
            // if there was no alert and an error was thrown than assign error to variable
            // if there was alert this block will be skipped and errorMessage will stay undefined
            errorMessage = e.message;
        }

        // this block will be executed if alert was present!
        // otherwise do nothing
        if (errorMessage !== undefined) {
           // ... your code here ...
        }
        // end of solution //
}
```

I checked my code and it is working, if still doesn't work, look for mistakes in YOUR part of the code